# How to using Snap.svg and Snap.js via angular-snap together?

Tags: angularjs, src, snap.svg

I try to use two dependencies:

```
"snap.svg": "~0.2.0", # snapsvg.io 
"angular-snap": "~1.4.1", # jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/
```

How I guess, it seems angular-snap uses a global Snap object as snap.svg and overrides the Snap object of Snap.svg.
In this order the Snap.svg functionalty goes away. If I revert the order of import, some Snap.js functionalty is missed.

Watch this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/rE4pNDqQnBh2e5wtqGUO?p=preview and swap the includes.

How can I use both libs?
Thx ahead!

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is going to be using a module loader like RequireJS to pull both Snap.js and Snap.svg into you application in a controlled way, it looks like both support AMD module loaders.

Unfortunately this will mean you won't be able to rely on the `snap-content` directive from Angular Snap anymore. You'll need to create a new Snap.js snapper instance yourself and make use of [`snapRemote#register`](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js#snapremoteregistersnapper-snapidl).

Here's some pseudo code:

```
require(['jakiestfu/Snap.js/snap'], function(SnapJS) {
  snapRemote.register(new SnapJS(snapOptions));
});

require(['adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/snap.svg'], function(SnapSVG) {
  // Do stuff with SnapSVG...
});
```

Also, you'll want to assign a `"snap-content"` class name to the element you initialize your snapper with (this is also usually handled by the `snap-content` directive).

**Edit**:

I'm not recommending this approach but it should work as well if you don't mind some hacks:

In your head:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.2.0/snap.svg.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script>
  // Save Snap.svg before it gets clobbered!
  window.SnapSVG = Snap;
</script>
<script src="snap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

After that you could go on using the svg Snap as SnapSVG or whatever you want to call it. The module loader approach is arguably better in almost any way you want to look at it... unless you need to ship tomorrow :).

**Edit 2**:

I just released v1.5.0 of Angular Snap which makes the Snap.js constructor an injected dependency rather than something we just look for on the window. You could now provide your own constructor, maybe saving it before it gets clobbered:

```
myApp.config(function(SnapConstructorProvider) {
  SnapConstructorProvider.use(window.Snap);
});
```

Using this you'll still be able to take advantage of the `snap-content` directive even if you pull in the Snap.js script with a module loader.

Comment: Edited with an alternative... it's a hack to be sure but you may not be too keen on reorganizing everything to use a module loader.